# How to register a JSF managed bean programmatically?

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, managed-bean

I'd like to register/add a Managed Bean class programmatically (from within a Servlet init()) into application scope.
How can I do that with JSF 1.2?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> *from within a Servlet `init()`*

So, it concerns a non-JSF request. The `FacesContext#getCurrentInstance()` would return `null` here, so it's of no use for you here.

It's good to know that JSF application scoped managed beans are basically stored as an attribute of the `ServletContext`. In the `init()` method you've the `ServletContext` at your hands by the inherited [`getServletContext()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext%28%29) method. So, the following should do:

```
@Override
public void init() {
    getServletContext().setAttribute("managedBeanName", new BackingBean());
}
```

That's it. It'll be available in JSF by `#{managedBeanName}`.

Comment: Do you know whether anything changed in that matter (programmatic bean registration) since 2011? Or do they at least consider it for instance in Java 8 to add this feature to standard? I can't find any info which would confirm or deny it.

Answer (score 19):

It is unlikely that can do do this in a programmatic manner from your application for managed beans of all scopes. BalusC has already pointed out how to do this for application scoped managed beans.

Having taken a look at how managed beans are registered in Mojarra 2.1 (a JSF 2.1 implementation); there isn't a lot of lot of elegant options available for programmatic registration of session and request scoped beans. Simply put, you either have to invoke the implementation specific classes, or you will have to create and destroy i.e. manage the beans yourself instead of relying on the JSF implementation to do this.

**Populating the request and session scopes with the beans (the unmanaged way)**

Note - This is referred to as the "unmanaged way" because you are constructing the beans, and not the container. Annotations like `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` will not work, unless you process them yourself and invoke the appropriate methods. Even dependency-injection won't work.

EL expressions are always evaluated at runtime, so it gives you enough opportunity to populate the scope with the beans before evaluation (which allows for shooting yourself in the foot, if you have the chance to do so). In Mojarra (and possibly other JSF implementations), the EL resolver will rely on the services of a ScopeHandler (or an equivalent class) to resolve the EL expression values. Mojarra uses the classes `ApplicationScopeHandler`, `RequestScopeHandler` and `SessionScopeHandler` to obtain the values from the different scopes.

You can populate the contents of the Session and Request scopes after after a new session is created, or before a request is processed by the JSF implementation.

Session scope population can be done (ideally using a `HttpSessionListener`) using:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
session == null ? null : session.setAttribute("<keyname>", new Bean());
```

The `keyname` must match the values you are using to reference the bean in EL expressions.

In a similar manner, you can populate the request scope (ideally done in a filter) using:

```
ServletRequest request = ... // get the reference to the servlet request object
request.setAttribute("<keyname>", new Bean());
```

If you need to understand how this works, you should take a look at the classes `com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap`, `com.sun.faces.context.RequestMap` and `com.sun.faces.context.ApplicationMap` to see how the context maps are managed internally, and used by the `SessionScopeHandler`, `RequestScopeHandler` and `ApplicationScopeHandler` classes that are static inner classes of the `ScopeManager` (another static inner) class of the `com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager` class. The `BeanManager` class is the one that contains the managed bean registrations, and the next section discusses how to "hack into" the registration process of Mojarra.

**Using the Mojarra classes to register the beans**

Registration of managed beans in the Mojarra implementation is done by the `public void register(ManagedBeanInfo beanInfo)` method of the `com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager` class. It is not trivial to access the `BeanManager` class using the JSF or Servlet APIs alone. There is however the `ApplicationAssociate` class of Mojarra that creates the `BeanManager` instance, and can be accessed using the `getCurrentInstance()` method. The other answer by Thomas already demonstartes how to register the managed bean programmatically:

```
ApplicationAssociate.getCurrentInstance().getBeanManager().register(...)
```

There is a caveat with the above approach. It is unlikely that this approach will work in the init method of `Servlet` for the simple reason that the `getCurrentInstance` method relies on a ThreadLocal variable to retrieve the `ApplicationAssociate` instance. The thread local variable is initialized by the `com.sun.faces.application.WebappLifecycleListener` class, so you must reproduce the mechanism used by the `WebappLifecycleListener` class, of invoking the `ApplicationAssociate getInstance(ServletContext context)` method, to gain access to the `ApplicationAssociate` instance. The following code therefore, *might be* (as I have not attempted using it) a better one, if you are willing to use Mojarra specific classes:

```
ServletContext sc = ... //get the ServletContext reference;
ApplicationAssociate.getInstance(sc).getBeanManager().register(...)
```

You must still watch out for quirks arising out of this mechanism as it is quite possible that some of the Mojarra classes and instances would not have been loaded or initialized before your Servlet. I would therefore suggest loading attempting to configure your servlet with a `load-on-startup` value that is higher than the one used by the `FacesServlet`.

Comment: Vineet, what a valuable completion of the topic. Too sad that there is only one green checkmark. :)

Comment: @Mulmoth, I don't mind. There's always the upvote button though :)

Answer (score 3):

Try `FacesContext.currentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().put(name, bean);`, i.e. put the managed bean instance into the map using the name you want to use in your expressions.

Edit:

To register the bean, try calling: `ApplicationAssociate.getCurrentInstance().getBeanManager().register(...)` and pass a `ManagedBeanInfo` you filled.

Comment: This would just put the bean in application scope, it won't be registered as a managed bean dynamically [unless if it is marked already]

Comment: Please note that the `FacesContext` is **not** available in a plain vanilla servlet. The `getCurrentInstance()` would only return null. I'm not sure about `ApplicationAssociate`, but that's actually a poor practice since you're tight coupling the code to a specific JSF implementation (in this case, Mojarra). You should try to avoid importing/using implementation specific code and prefer programming against the abstract API (like as you would do for JDBC, Servlets, and so on).

Comment: @BalusC yes, programming against the abstract api is preferable. I'd also not bother whether the application associate know about the bean or not, as long as I could access it using expressions etc. It's just that @Mulmoth asked for `register` and @Joshi said registering would mean more that putting it into application scope.

Answer (score 1):

The following code registers the managed bean correcly using `FacesContext`, but it requires the servlet request and response. You could use the code and initialize it lazily using servlet and not during the init.

Usage:

```
UserBean ub = (UserBean) 
    Example.getBean(servletRequest, servletResponse, "user", UserBean.class);
```

Source:

```
import javax.el.ExpressionFactory;
import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.faces.FactoryFinder;
import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory;
import javax.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleFactory;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

class Example {

    public static Object getBean(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String beanName, Class expectedType){
        FacesContext ctx = getFacesContext(request, response);
        ValueExpression vex = ctx.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(ctx.getELContext(), "#{"+beanName+"}", expectedType);
        return vex.getValue(ctx.getELContext());
    }

    private static FacesContext getFacesContext(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if (facesContext == null) {
            facesContext = ((FacesContextFactory) FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.FACES_CONTEXT_FACTORY)).
                getFacesContext(request.getSession().getServletContext(), request, response, 
                ((LifecycleFactory) FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.LIFECYCLE_FACTORY))
                .getLifecycle(LifecycleFactory.DEFAULT_LIFECYCLE));

            InnerFacesContext.setFacesContextAsCurrentInstance(facesContext);
            facesContext.setViewRoot(facesContext.getApplication().getViewHandler().createView(facesContext, ""));
        }
        return facesContext;
    }

    private abstract static class InnerFacesContext extends FacesContext {
        protected static void setFacesContextAsCurrentInstance(FacesContext facesContext) {
            FacesContext.setCurrentInstance(facesContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Say I have registered my beans using

```
ApplicationAssociate.getInstance(sc).getBeanManager().register(...)
```

Now It is working fine, But then there is a server restart and
my beans are destroyed, How on startup I can get the same bean registered.